# Sonatype Nexus. Настройка yum репозиториев

Tags: linux, centos, repository, redhat, yum

Возможно кто-нибудь сможет мне здесь помочь.

Я создал hosted репозиторий yum в Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.34.0-01, и наполнил его пакетами как показано на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

также я создал файл /etc/yum.repos.d/Nexus.repo на машине-клиенте:

```
[root@repo0 yum.repos.d]# cat Nexus.repo
[nexusrepo]
name=Nexus - Repository
#baseurl=http://localhost:8081/repository/RedHat-based/packages/m/mc/
baseurl=http://localhost:8081/repository/RedHat-based/
gpgcheck=0
repo_gpgcheck=0
priority=1
enabled=1
```

Очевидно, что при попытке обращения к репозиторию yum ругается на отсутствие файла repodata/repomd.xml:

```
[root@repo0 yum.repos.d]# yum update
Загружены модули: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
http://localhost:8081/repository/RedHat-based/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Пробуем другое зеркало.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.

No packages marked for update
```

Хотелось бы понять как мне сгенерировать файл repomd.xml, который будет общим для всей структуры каталогов репозитория или это невозможно и я должен размещать все пакеты в одной директории?